# How to reference both System managed identity and user managed identity in ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I wanted to know how to assign both system managed identity as well as user managed identity on a single VM in ARM template?

For example, I have ARM template with user managed identity like below:

```
"identity":{
        "type":"UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities":{
           "[resourceId(variables('userAssignedIdentitySubscription'),variables('userAssignedIdentityResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('userAssignedIdentityName'))]":{
           }
        }
     },
```

if I want to use System managed identity, should I add another dict in identity with type as system managed identity? Like:

```
"identity":{
        "type":"UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities":{
           "[resourceId(variables('userAssignedIdentitySubscription'),variables('userAssignedIdentityResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('userAssignedIdentityName'))]":{
           }
        }
     },
    {
        "type":"SystemAssigned"
     }
```

OR there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, to use both System managed identity and User managed identity, below is the simple way:

```
"identity":{
    "type":"SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities":{
       "[resourceId(variables('userAssignedIdentitySubscription'),variables('userAssignedIdentityResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('userAssignedIdentityName'))]":{
       }
    }
 },
```

Easy TIP to find ARM template related answers: I found the answer by manually creating a VM with both type of identities, and exported ARM template from Azure portal and found the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Was looking to implement user-managed instance in bicep,

If you have previously created a user-managed instance resource. E.g.

```js
resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: managedIdentityName
  location: location
}
```

```js
identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned, UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.Id}': {}
    }
}
```

If you need to don't have that, you just need to fulfill this line

```js
userAssignedIdenties: {
'/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-id>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<userMI-name>':{}
}
```

Also, use the provided functions to generate if it gets hard to maintain:
`var resourceId = '${resourceGroup().id}/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<managed-identity-name>' )`

`<managed-identity-name>` could be a parameter, variable or a hard-coded string

`resourceGroup().id` gives you `/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-id>/`